# Artifactory Service Unavailable for frontend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I have a problem with a non-working frontend in Artifactory.

The backend is working and I can pull / push in docker:

```
023-04-06T13:45:02.839Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [hash] [server_bearer.go:95           ] [main                ] - Failed to create/update server info, err: servers find by id failed, cannot find server with id (7c73fd201be3)
2023-04-06T13:45:25.594Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [hash] [yMetadataClientConfigStore:122] [art-init            ] - Unable to request the Metadata Service Service-Id: Failed executing api/v1/system/service_id, with response code: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found and response message: Not Found
```

I tried recreating the container but that didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error about the **Metadata Service** might be related to the DB connection string set in the system.yaml file.
If a DB string was not added for the Metadata service specifically in system.yaml file you may try to add it manually and check if this behavior persists.

In addition, you can refer to this Knowledge-base article about "[Troubleshooting the Metadata Service](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-troubleshooting-the-metadata-service/)" in case you encounter any further difficulties (regrading the DB string, refer to step #4)